# Decoding Json online to string in Python

Tags: python, json, decode

i want to decode this json
https://deathsnacks.com/wf/data/voidtraders.json

```
[{u'Node': u'Kronia Relay (Saturn)', u'NodeIndex': 0, u'ManifestIndex': 0, u'Manifest': None, u'Activation': {u'usec': 0, u'sec': 1520604000}, u'Character': u"Baro'Ki Teel", u'Expiry': {u'usec': 0, u'sec': 1520773200}, u'_id': {u'id': u'5967933ca351963d1cd7faa5'}, u'Config': None, u'NextRotation': None}]
```

with Python and get the reply like this

```
Node: Kronia Relay (Saturn)
Activation: X min
Character: Baro'Ki Teel
Expiry: X min
```

etc etc

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jhpratt i have this online json, and i need to parse it for a telegram bot, so in a human-readable way.
johnashu, i've tried a basic json
import urllib, json
url = "https://deathsnacks.com/wf/data/voidtraders.json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
But i don't know how to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests, json, pprint
r = requests.get('https://deathsnacks.com/wf/data/voidtraders.json').text
data = json.loads(r)
pprint.pprint(data)

[{'Activation': {'sec': 1520604000, 'usec': 0},
  'Character': "Baro'Ki Teel",
  'Config': None,
  'Expiry': {'sec': 1520773200, 'usec': 0},
  'Manifest': None,
  'ManifestIndex': 0,
  'NextRotation': None,
  'Node': 'Kronia Relay (Saturn)',
  'NodeIndex': 0,
  '_id': {'id': '5967933ca351963d1cd7faa5'}}]
```

You can also iterate over the dictionary items:

```
for key,value in data.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: Thanks! better then mine simple code.
Can you link me a guide to include a dictionary?
my goal is to clean the json from non-necessary characters like [{'
Also, it's a dynamic json, it will change with more information, so i should define all the informations into a dictionary to avoid any problem.

Comment: A dictionary is just a data type involving key-value pairs. You can access a dictionary item's value using bracket notation: `my_dict[item]` returns `value`. Since your data is changing, just loop through the entire process of requesting the data and storing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!